# Calderón–Zygmund lemma and Lebesgue measure

Tags: fourier-analysis, homotopy-theory

Can someone please explain the relationship between the Calderón–Zygmund lemma and Lebesgue measure, thanks.

Comment: This is quite an awkward question to answer. Could you possibly be a little more specific?

Comment: What you have tried? Explain it...